# How can I use a range slider with django-filter?

Tags: django, django-filters

How to use a range slider (for example the jQuery one) with django-filter package?

So now I'm using the RangeFilter which just displays to normal text fields for the range. So the search function is working perfectly fin but it's just not that fancy as a cool slider.

```py
class TentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    width = django_filters.NumberFilter(label="Breite")
    length = django_filters.NumberFilter(label="Länge")
    number_of_People = RangeFilter(label="People range")

    class Meta:
        model = Tent
        fields = ['width', 'length', 'number_of_People', ]
```

I really would appreciate help because this thing is stressing me out.

Answer (score 0):

Any non-filter arguments are passed to a filter's underlying form field. e.g.,

```
class TentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    number_of_people = RangeFilter(label='People range', widget=MyCustomWidget)
```

When the form is generated, the form field generated for `number_of_people` will use the given widget. If that's insufficient and you need to customize the form, there's also the `Meta.form` option where you can pass a custom `Form` class.

Answer (score 0):

I have a made detailed tutorial on how to do create a jQuery range-slider with django-crispy-forms and django-filters. Hope it will be helpful.
Link to the tutorial https://mmtechslv.medium.com/how-to-create-a-fancy-range-slider-filter-in-django-890bd0486e13

Comment: This demo is really nice but I am struggling to apply it to date range filters. I have a date field and would like to extract only the year for a filter.

`birth_date__year = BirthYearRangeFilter(label='Birth Year', field_name='birth_date', lookup_expr='year')`





`class BirthYearRangeFilter(RangeFilter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        min_value = 1950
        max_value = 2020
        self.extra['widget'] = CustomRangeWidget(attrs={'data-range_min':min_value,'data-range_max':max_value})`

Any ideas what's wrong?